# Looking to use a library with example code for Open Quantum Safe

Tags: c, gcc, cmake, ninja

So I am trying to use following library: [Open Quantum Safe](https://github.com/open-quantum-safe/liboqs/wiki/Minimal-example-of-a-post-quantum-KEM)

I am using windows linux subsystem, so I followed the linux setup. I think I followed all the steps correctly, as I didnt have any errors.

I next wanted to run the example provided here: [example KEM](https://github.com/open-quantum-safe/liboqs/wiki/Minimal-example-of-a-post-quantum-KEM)

This example code is also in the repo.

When I run the command suggested at the bottom of the second link I get the following:

> /usr/bin/ld: build/lib/liboqs.a(aes_ossl.c.o): in function `OQS_AES128_ECB_load_schedule': aes_ossl.c:(.text.OQS_AES128_ECB_load_schedule+0x2b): undefined reference to` EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new'
> /usr/bin/ld: aes_ossl.c:(.text.OQS_AES128_ECB_load_schedule+0x39): undefined reference to `EVP_aes_128_ecb' /usr/bin/ld: aes_ossl.c:(.text.OQS_AES128_ECB_load_schedule+0x4d): undefined reference to` EVP_EncryptInit_ex'
> /usr/bin/ld: aes_ossl.c:(.text.OQS_AES128_ECB_load_schedule+0x61): undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding' /usr/bin/ld: build/lib/liboqs.a(aes_ossl.c.o): in function` OQS_AES128_free_schedule':
> aes_ossl.c:(.text.OQS_AES128_free_schedule+0x17): undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free' /usr/bin/ld: build/lib/liboqs.a(aes_ossl.c.o): in function` OQS_AES128_ECB_enc':
> aes_ossl.c:(.text.OQS_AES128_ECB_enc+0x71): undefined reference to `EVP_EncryptUpdate' /usr/bin/ld: aes_ossl.c:(.text.OQS_AES128_ECB_enc+0x8c): undefined reference to` EVP_EncryptFinal_ex'
> /usr/bin/ld: aes_ossl.c:(.text.OQS_AES128_ECB_enc+0xa9): undefined reference to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free'

and another 50 or so lines of the same type of errors.

This error is clearly telling me it cannot find functions, or files that it needs to compile, but I am not sure why? Some of these functions I cannot even locate.

My guess is that I somehow built the files wrong, but I am unsure.

If anyone has any experience with this library, or maybe wants to help me with the specifics, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you're not linking the SSL library — either missing it altogether or not linking it in the right sequence.

Comment: Hmmm, You may be correct. I was not really looking at the SSL library as my end goal was to execute this on some sort of hardware and I didn't think the SSL library would be relevant but maybe they are dependent on each other.

Comment: The command line `$CC -Ibuild/include -Lbuild/lib tests/example_kem.c -o example_kem -loqs` is correct when oqs is built as **shared** library (`liboqs.so`), which incorporates all its dependencies. In case of **static** library (`liboqs.a`) you need to link with its dependencies manually.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you! This was exactly the problem. I had to set the library path to the .SO file, but after that, it ran correctly. Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Tsyvarev, I was using a static library which is why it was not able to find the dependencies. Once I used the dynamic library I was able to run the code.

Specific answer if you are using this exact library:

```
 cmake -GNinja .. -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON
```

I also had to set the Path to the .so file:

```
 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/liboqs/build/lib
```

I also did ldconfig, not sure if that was necessary or not.